# Installing vagrant plugins on Windows 7 Home and Professional Edition

Tags: windows, vagrant-plugin

This is my first SO post. Apologies for my poor markdown.

My question relates to installing vagrant plugins on a Windows 7 host. In summary, it appears that I am unable to install vagrant plugins from a 'fresh install'

**Tried:**

- Standard vagrant plugin install for multiple plugins
- Specifying rubygems.org as a plugin source
- Downloading gem from rubygems, and installing locally
- Running devkitvars.bat before vagrant plugin install
- Administrator CMD.exe vs user CMD.exe vs Git BASH.
- Deleting user folders (.vagrant.d), cache folders (etc!)
- Disabling unused network adapters (in this case, VirtualBox's)

**Versions**

- Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 - 64 Bit
- Vagrant 1.8.3 (via MSI installer)
- VirtualBox 5.0.6 (expect this is irrelevant)
- RubyGems: 2.4.5.1
- Ruby: 2.2.3 for i386-mingw32 (these were installed by vagrant- see Gems environment output below)

I have freshly installed vagrant via its MSI installer at https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html.
The vagrant version it installs is currently 1.8.3.

I've installed to the default directory: C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant.
I have restarted, and the embedded/bin directory is on my path (i.e. the ruby/ gems executables and others).

I am trying to install the following plugins: vagrant-hostsupdater and vagrant-triggers for use with VVV. However, I have also attempted a few 'random' plugin installs with the exact same observed behaviour.

Running "vagrant plugin install " in a CMD prompt with Administrator privileges produces the basic error (of 'bundler') of:
*"Checksum of /versions does not match the checksum provided by server! Something is wrong"*.

Thus the plugin does not install. The same error occurs for Git-BASH, and for a non-privileged (=user) command prompt.

If I attempt to install the 'gem' via "gem install" using the embedded gem executable in ".\vagrant\embedded\bin", the gem installs without error. However it is obviously not registered with vagrant and not listed with "vagrant plugin list".

I have downloaded the vagrant-hostsupdater gem from rubygems.org; and attempted to install from the local gem.
I.e. "vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostsupdater-1.0.2.gem". This produces a different displayed error: *"Cannot not find gem 'vagrant-hostsupdater (=1.0.2) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine"*.

I have also tried things like: reinstalling gem/ reinstalling bundle, deleting the ~.vagrant.d and ~.bundle folders (where ~ is C:\Users\my-username). Unfortunately I gleaned these things from a variety of online posts, and my changes weren't systematic. Nonetheless, nothing like this has worked.

---

I am new user of Vagrant, and have never used Ruby/ Gems before (Until today I thought *rake*s were for gardening)

- Running Gem environment produces: RubyGems Environment:

  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5.1
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.3 (2015-08-18 patchlevel 173) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: C:/Users/Owner/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: C:/ProgramData
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

    - ruby
    - x86-mingw32
  - GEM PATHS:

    - C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
    - C:/Users/Owner/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:

    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:

    - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:

    - C:\ffmpeg\bin
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\K-Lite Codec Pack\Media Player Classic
    - C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin\
    - C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib\
    - C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\include\
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
    - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
    - C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
    - C:\Windows\system32
    - C:\Windows
    - C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
    - C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
    - C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
    - C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared
    - C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\
    - C:\Users\Owner.dnx\bin
    - C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\
    - C:\Program Files\nodejs\
    - C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin
    - C:\HashiCorp\embedded\bin
    - D:\Projects\Sarj\Applications\ImageMagick-6.9.2-5
    - C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
    - C:\Program Files (x86)\FX 2\Common
    - C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\atom\bin
    - D:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\
    - C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm
    - D:\Users\Jonathon\Documents\GitHub\vv
    - C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\bin
    - C:\Users\Owner

---

The following SO posts DO NOT solve my problem:
stackoverflow.com/questions/29352622/vagrant-plugin-install-fails-for-any-plugin
stackoverflow.com/questions/33490258/failed-to-install-vagrant-cachier-plugin-on-windows

### stackoverflow.com/questions/20146758/vagrant-plugin-install-vagrant-windows-fails   (I tried to disable the virtualbox adapter, with no success)

I am experiencing the same problem on a Windows 7 professional laptop, with the same vagrant install.

I have read online that windows development using Ruby may require the ruby "devkit". However my understanding is that Vagrant bundles its own devkit, and hence installing a separate Ruby devkit is NOT required (?)
To that end, I naively ran the "devkitvars.bat"  file in .\Vagrant\embedded, before attemping the vagrant plugin install, with yet the same effects.

Now I understand Vagrant and Windows might not be the best mix; however my preference is to continue with Vagrant on Windows.

Thank you for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to have been fixed by an upgrade to the Vagrant 1.8.4 windows installer.

I.e.: both the plugins: vagrant-hostsupdater and vagrant-triggers install perfectly now.